# Error position in recursive FParsec expressions

Tags: error-handling, f#, grammar, fparsec

My grammar contains expressions characterized by an identifier that only optionally is followed by a parenthesized list of expressions.

My problem is that Fparsec will show an "unintuitive" position on syntax errors when the error occurs in a nested expression.

For an example, consider this simple parser

```
let x = skipChar 'x' .>> spaces >>% Node.X 
let y = skipChar 'y' .>> spaces >>% Node.Y
let c = skipChar ',' .>> spaces 
let left = pchar '(' .>> spaces 
let right = pchar ')' .>> spaces 
let expr, exprRef = createParserForwardedToRef()
let paramList, paramListRef = createParserForwardedToRef()
let paramTuple = left >>. paramList .>> right 


let xOrY = choice [x ; y] 
let exprWithArgs = xOrY .>>. paramTuple |>> Node.Expr

exprRef.Value <- choice [ attempt exprWithArgs ; xOrY ] 
paramListRef.Value <- sepBy1 expr c

let parser = expr .>> eof
let result = run parser "x(y, y, y(x, y, y(x,y)) )"

printf "\nParsing correct:\n%O" result 

let resultWithError = run parser "x(y, y, y(x, y, y(x,z)) )"
printf "\n\nParsing error:\n%O" resultWithError
```

The output of the program is:

```
Parsing correct:
Success: Expr (X, [Y; Y; Expr (Y, [X; Y; Expr (Y, [X; Y])])])

Parsing error:
Failure:
Error in Ln: 1 Col: 2
x(y, y, y(x, y, y(x,z)) )
 ^
Expecting: end of input
```

The more nested expressions I have, the more difficult it becomes to find the actual erroneous position.

Is there a way to change my grammar (or to use/configure) FParsec in such a way that the error becomes better to find? I wished, I would get an intuitive error message like this:

```
Parsing correct:
Success: Expr (X, [Y; Y; Expr (Y, [X; Y; Expr (Y, [X; Y])])])

Parsing error:
Failure:
Error in Ln: 1 Col: 21
x(y, y, y(x, y, y(x,z)) )
                    ^
Expecting: 'x' or 'y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `"y(x,z)"` as an example input. The problem occurs in the `expr`/`exprRef` parser. First, it attempts to parse `exprWithArgs`, which fails because of the `z`. The parser backtracks (because of `attempt`), and tries to parse `xOrY` instead, which succeeds on the `y`. But the next char is `(` instead of `eof`, so `parser` then fails at that position with an unhelpful message.

Since `exprWithArgs` starts by parsing `xOrY`, we can factor that out, leading to this solution:

```ml
exprRef.Value <-
    parse {
        let! xy = xOrY
        match! opt paramTuple with
            | Some args -> return Node.Expr (xy, args)
            | None -> return xy
    }
```

This has the advantage of not backtracking, so the parser always moves forward until it can't proceed further, resulting in a clearer error message. Note that `exprWithArgs` is no longer used.

If you don't like the computation builder, you can do this instead:

```ml
exprRef.Value <-
    pipe2
        xOrY
        (opt paramTuple)
        (fun xy argsOpt ->
            match argsOpt with
                | Some args -> Node.Expr (xy, args)
                | None -> xy)
```

Output is now:

```ml
Parsing correct:
Success: Expr (X, [Y; Y; Expr (Y, [X; Y; Expr (Y, [X; Y])])])

Parsing error:
Failure:
Error in Ln: 1 Col: 21
x(y, y, y(x, y, y(x,z)) )
                    ^
Expecting: 'x' or 'y'
```

There might be simpler solutions as well, but I think this does what you want.

Comment: That is a nice solution, thank you. After experimenting a little bit, if you are willing to change the type Node.Expr to be Node * (Node list) option, the simple 

exprRef.Value <- xOrY .>>. opt paramTuple |>> Node.Expr

would also do the trick. It also became about 15% faster than my original version. I guess because now, the parser doesn't need to do any backtracking.